# Is this 230v motor wired for 115v operation

Tags: electrical, wiring, air-conditioning, electric-motor, heat-pump

I have the following wiring diagram for the motor I am replacing.

[image: My current motor]

After looking at the wiring as shown here, I see one black and one purple wired to the terminals. There is a second set that is just wired together & has a wire cap on them. Does this mean the motor I am replacing is wired for 115V operation? My end question is, can I replace this motor with a 115V motor?

[image: Current Wiring part 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 120v motor cannot be installed in place of the motor shown.  This is a single voltage PSC condenser fan motor nominally rated for 200-230v only and it is not intended to be wired for 115v.

Also, there is probably no 120v circuit available in the location where the motor is being used.  Double no.  In other words, hooking up a 120v motor in place of this unit would be a no-no.

This is a very ordinary condenser fan motor with compatible replacements stocked by many supply houses.  When replacing this motor, the run capacitor should also be replaced at the same time because run capacitors are often in poor condition by the time this type of motor fails, and the new replacement motor may require a run capacitor that is a different size than the original.